# 2 tabs in yii framework

Tags: yii

I'm now task to create a website using a yii as a framework. I would like to as for your help on how will i be able to display 2 tabs with grid view on each tab. I was able to create tabs but every time i put a grid view in the tab, the 1st tab will not display the grid view and only the last tab will display the grid view.

here's the code of the 1st and 2nd tab

```
     <div id="gridview-claims">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        if ($gif.content) {
            $.extend($gif.content, {
                //DO SYSTEM SPECIFIC STUFF AFTER CONTENT IS LOADED
                onload : function (content) {
                //APPLY FLEXGRID TO TABLES
                $.get('/ADS/index.php/claims/admin', function (data) {
                    content.find('#gridview-claims').html(data);
                    });                 
                    }
                });
            }
            </script>
            </div>


<div id="tb-2-content" class="tb-content hidden">
            <div id="gridview-deduction">
            <script type="text/javascript">
            if ($gif.content) {
                $.extend($gif.content, {
                //DO SYSTEM SPECIFIC STUFF AFTER CONTENT IS LOADED
                onload : function (content) {
                //APPLY FLEXGRID TO TABLES
                $.get('/ADS/index.php/deduction/admin', function (data) {
                content.find('#gridview-deduction').html(data);

                    });         

                    }
                });
            }
            </script>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the jquery widget in Yii instead, then.  For each tab you can then use a render function to display your your grids.

For example:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiTabs', array(
        'tabs'=>array(
            'Pediatric Info'=> $this->renderPartial("_view", array('data' => $model, 'patientID'=> $model->id), true, true), 
            'Contacts' =>$this->renderPartial("_viewContacts", array('data' => $model, 'patientID'=> $model->id), true, true), 
            // panel 3 contains the content rendered by a partial view
            'Insurance'=> $this->renderPartial("_viewInsurance", array('data' => $model, 'patientID'=> $model->id), true, true), 
            'Activities' =>$this->renderPartial("_viewEncounters", array('data' => $model, 'patientID'=> $model->id), true, true), 
        ),
        // additional javascript options for the tabs plugin
        'options'=>array('collapsible'=>true,),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

2 tabs with two forms works for me..

```
  <?php
      $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiTabs', array(
        'tabs'=>array(
             'Share By Email'=> $this->renderPartial("_form", array('model' => $model), true, true), 
             'Share to Friends'=> $this->renderPartial("_friendsform", array('model' => $model), true, true), 


        ),
        // additional javascript options for the tabs plugin
        'options'=>array('collapsible'=>true,),
    ));


?>
```